# Line thickness of 0.5px (1 real pixel) on a retina display in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, safari

How can I draw a line with mobile safari that is one real pixel wide on a retina display?

I tried:

`border-bottom:0.5px solid #fff;`

and

`border-bottom:0.05em solid #fff;`

with different values between 0.01em and 0.1em.

Mobile Safari always draws a line that is one pixel wide (2 pixels on a retina display) or none at all. How can I make mobile safari draw a line that is one real pixel (0.5px) wide ?

Comment: How about using something like .05em?

Comment: @sheriffderek: Thanks for the tip. Tried it with differen em values, but it didn't work. Either safari showed a 1px wide line (2 real px) or none at all.

Comment: I found this, but I also read that iOS6 doesnt play nice. http://bradbirdsall.com/mobile-web-in-high-resolution

Comment: Here is a talk about pixels: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wscVOXjIzQ#at=324

Comment: @sheriffderek: thanks for the research. I'll take a look at the video as soon as possible. The first link doesn't make me hopefull. Seems to be an almost hopeless case - except using tweaks like the one mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you have a 0.5px border on a Retina Display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640521/can-you-have-a-0-5px-border-on-a-retina-display)

Comment: It's a duplicate. But the answer to the other question was not sufficient, the answer here is currently the best one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use scale. The style below will give you hairline

```
 .transform-border-hairline {
     border-bottom: 1px #ff0000 solid;
     transform: scaleY(0.5);
 }
```

More specificly (and that trick in live use) here http://atirip.com/2013/09/22/yes-we-can-do-fraction-of-a-pixel/

Comment: Did not have the time yet to fully read the article - but that seems to be it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `border-width: 0.5px`

Safari 8 (in both iOS and OS X) brings `border-width: 0.5px`. You can use that if you’re ready to accept that current versions of Android and old versions of iOS and OS X will just show a regular border (a fair compromise in my opinion).

You can’t use this directly though, because browsers that don’t know about `0.5px` borders will interpret it as `0px`. No border. So what you need to do is add a class to your `<html>` element when it is supported:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio && devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
  var testElem = document.createElement('div');
  testElem.style.border = '.5px solid transparent';
  document.body.appendChild(testElem);
  if (testElem.offsetHeight == 1)
  {
    document.querySelector('html').classList.add('hairlines');
  }
  document.body.removeChild(testElem);
}
// This assumes this script runs in <body>, if it runs in <head> wrap it in $(document).ready(function() {   })
```

Then, using retina hairlines becomes really easy:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.hairlines div {
  border-width: 0.5px;
}
```

Best of all, you can use border-radius with it. And you can use it with the 4 borders (top/right/bottom/left) as easily.

Source: http://dieulot.net/css-retina-hairline

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally suggest using .5 in pixels ever really. But you want a fallback to it.

just place the fallback on top. Like this.

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid #fff;
```

Comment: Actually, I am not looking for a fallback. I am looking for a way to print a 1-real-pixel wide line on the iPhone screen.

Comment: but you would want some sort of fall-back - so that It could be seen on the desktop, right?

Comment: Well, it makes sense to have a fallback. But before I need a fallback I need a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Many phones are now 3x (3 real pixels for each logical pixel).

Therefore 0.5px mathematically equates to 1.5 real pixels - which is impossible to render consistently.

So if you're trying to put a 0.5px border around something it's physically impossible for it to be consistent. Now the browser may decide to always round it to 1 real pixel or 2 real pixels OR it may try to anti-alias it. Unfortunately not even 'thin' as a thickness renders as one device pixel.

The worse case scanerio is it will use 1 pixel on one edge and 2 pixels on another which will end up looking awful. So be sure to keep this in mind and test on a 3x phone.