# Can I have 12.5px font size?

Tags: css

It's already 2019, iPhone retina invented near 10 years, as you may know, you can now use [0.5px as border width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640521/can-you-have-a-0-5px-border-on-a-retina-display) in CSS3, and most of iPhone and Android devices can correctly solve it as 1px in retina screen.

My question is, if I specify `font-size: 12px`, actually it will show a font size with 24px in retina screen. If I want to show 25px font in retina screen, can I use `font-size: 12.5px`? Thanks!

---

I asked our UI designer, she said she will use 750px as width when designing for mobile. So that means if she set a text font size as 28px, I will divide it by 2, so I should use 14px in my css, right?

But that bring another question: the UI designer can only design by 22px, 24px, 26px, 28px and so on, so I can divide by 2, to get 11px, 12px, ... in css.

If UI designer set font size as 25px, we cannot use 12.5px in css. I've tried to set font-size: 12.5px, but it won't work, browsers simply convert it as 13px.

How to exactly set it as UI picture?

---

@Josh Lee, Thank you very much! I tried your code in desktop Chrome browser, it shows like below:

[image: desktop chrome]

This is great! However, if I run the code in Safari of the newest iPhone iOS 12.3.1, it shows as below:

[image: ios safari]

You can see that iPhone still cannot correctly show .5 font size, it will either change it to 12px or 13px, just cannot be 12.5px.

I also tried the code on Android Chrome, it shows correctly.

iPhone really sucks.

Comment: Why would you want it to be 1 real px on retina? I would leave technical size out of  perceivable size. I would rather enjoy image quality, than messing with UI design. I'd use `@media` for special retina cases and use PX as integers. - Short answer: you *can*.

Comment: You can zoom Chrome to 200% to find out (or use the device emulation mode).

Comment: Or simply try this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fo4egv7n/ does the font size changes when PX are in decimals?

Comment: Pixel perfect designs went out of style in this century, try telling this your UI designer ;)

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA REM will finally convert to PX to show on screen, so even I use REM, it calculate a result of 12.5px, it will still show 13px in mobile browsers.

Comment: @ZhangBuzz Looks like Safari and iOS don't support this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fractional px font size is perfectly valid.

Modern browsers perform layout with device-independent floating-point values, and there are few-to-no differences between running on a high resolution (2x, 1.25x, etc.) display and setting the zoom level in a browser.

You should be aware that certain values are rounded to whole pixels, such as borders, and this difference might manifest in subtle ways.

As an illustration, Firefox reports `1px` for the computed border width of all these, while Chrome does not. A box made purely of border width might layout differently in Firefox and Chrome — there's a tradeoff at play here.

Also as an illustration, do a Find in Page for "px" and look at the ragged border of the highlight — it smoothly moves to the right rather than jumping at a certain point.

Edit: And Safari (on Mac) is indeed the odd one out, apparently rounding the font size to a whole number for display (but the computed value is still fractional).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => {
  const {width, height} = span.getBoundingClientRect();
  span.textContent += `\t${width}x${height}`;
  const {borderTopWidth} = getComputedStyle(span);
  span.textContent += `\t${borderTopWidth}`;
});
```

```css
span {
  border: 0.08em solid silver;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:12.0px"><span>font-size:12.0px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.1px"><span>font-size:12.1px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.2px"><span>font-size:12.2px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.3px"><span>font-size:12.3px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.4px"><span>font-size:12.4px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.5px"><span>font-size:12.5px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.6px"><span>font-size:12.6px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.7px"><span>font-size:12.7px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.8px"><span>font-size:12.8px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:12.9px"><span>font-size:12.9px</span></div>
<div style="font-size:13.0px"><span>font-size:13.0px</span></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot paste picture here, please see my updated question with picture.